# Convergence in mean square and almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given the sample space [0,1] and the uniform probability measure P(.), random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ are defined by

[image]

How do I $X_n$ converges almost surely as n tends to infinity and also in mean square?

I am having difficulties as I dont know how to define $x(\omega)$ from which $\vert X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\vert$ can be calculated.

I am used to $X(\omega )$ being given in these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Almost sure convergence:
$$P(\{\omega : X_n(\omega) \to 0\}) = P([0,1))=1$$

Mean square convergence:
$$E((X_n-0)^2) = P(X_n \in (1-1/n,1]) = 1/n \to 0$$